# Attached PDF's are always empty - Laravel Mail

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send an email with an attached PDF. It works locally when using mailhog, but not in the live environment.

The mail sends and the PDF is there, but it's always just 0kb and will not open.

Here is the code:

```
    public function build()
    {
        $this->from(config('mail.from.address'), config('mail.from.name'))
            ->subject('Your PDF')
            ->attach($this->filePath);

        return $this->markdown('emails.pdf-download');
    }
```

The path definitely does exist and the file is valid.

Here is what the file looks like:

[image: Screenshot of file]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could be a permissions issue?

Comment: Turns out my local path and the path on the server were different.

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense.